# Recuperar dados do Firebase em outro App

Tags: android, firebase

Tenho um App do Usuário que envia uma solicitação que será recebida por um App da Empresa. Por enquanto o App do usuário envia dados que estão sendo gravados apenas no Firebase.

Como faço pra recuperar esses dados no outro App da Empresa? Tipo nome, endereço, foto, entre outras informações.

Comment: Do mesmo jeito que tu recuperaria no app do usuário, conecta o app ao mesmo firebase e usa do mesmo jeito

Comment: Conecta o outro App ao mesmo projeto do Firebase? Então tenho que criar as mesmas classes do app usuário no app da empresa? Correto?

Comment: Sim, quando você criou um projeto no console do firebase seguiu um passo a passo e ele te deu um arquivo e uns trechos para adicionar no arquivo de `graddle` se não me engano, faz a mesma coisa para o segundo app

Comment: Blz...Vou tentar aqui. Vlw